# SQL insert new rows but keep old value in conflicting keys

Tags: postgresql

Say I have two tables:

tb1:

```
id name date
1 John 01/01/2012
1 John 01/02/2012
2 James 02/02/2020
```

tb2:

```
id name date
1 John 01/01/2013
1 John 01/01/2012
```

The uniqueness of both `tb1` and `tb2` comes from the combination of `(id, name,date)` columns. Therefore I would like to insert only values from `tb2` that are new to `tb1`. In this case only `(1,John,01/01/2013)` would be inserted since the other row is already present in `tb1`.

My try is:

```
INSERT INTO tb1 (date) SELECT * FROM tb2 ON CONFLICT (id,name,date) DO NOTHING;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not tell us what the error is that you get. But just from a syntax check, it will result in the error:

> ERROR: INSERT has more expressions than target columns

because you specify one target columns, but provide three columns from the SELECT.

Assuming you did specify a unique constraint or primary key on the three columns, adding the additional columns in the INSERT statement should work:

```
INSERT INTO tb1 (id,name,date) 
SELECT id,name,date 
FROM tb2 ON CONFLICT (id,name,date) DO NOTHING;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL language is a non procedural language, just a query language... You must do this with queries, like :

```
INSERT INTO tb1 (id,name,date) 
SELECT * 
FROM   tb2 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                  FROM   tb1 INNER JOIN tb2 
                         ON ROW (tb1.id, tb1.name, tb1.date) = 
                            ROW (tb2.id, tb2.name, tb2.date));
```

Comment: I did not give you the -1, but I would if it were not already done. Two reasons: First, the query does not work. You selected 3 columns but are inserting only 1. Second, the explanation *is a non procedural language just a query language* is (imho) insufficient. But i will not give another -1, it is not that bad.

Comment: I guess you were downvoted because the statement still has the same syntax error as the one in the question. Plus: using the NOT EXISTS is much less efficient than the `on conflict do nothing` and it's not safe for concurrent use. It can still throw a unique key violation.